# How take icon color of selectmenu in th element

Tags: javascript, css, sorting, jquery-ui

I've a table. And When I click it's sort my table ascending. If I click again, it's a descending sort and click again to come back to 'no sort'

I've an i element where I manipulate class between ui-icon-caret-2-n-s/ui-icon-caret-1-n/ui-icon-caret-1-s to show which type of sort.

To have a beautifull displaying I use jquery-ui customisation in my header of table with class = ui-widget-header ui-state-default. But I want my arrows take same color that selectmenu element. 
Actually I use, *manually*

```
.ui-widget-header .ui-icon {Background-image : url('Pathgoodcolor');}
```

But I use this table in severals projects and I search a method to put *automatcally* same color as arrow of selectmenu element

**UPDATE**
I saw I need UI-Button Cause icon in selectmenu inherit from .ui-button .ui-icon
Bu if I Add ui-button it's add lots of not desired styles

Comment: Please have a look at [How to ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry if I've difficulties to explain exactly what I want. Perhaps my english is too rustig :-)
But finnally the solution is Put a div with class="ui-button" over the  like that

```
$(<div class="TFOhd ui-button TFOOptlstFiltreImg" ><i class="ui-icon ui-icon-caret-2-n-s"></i></div>').appendTo($Col);
```

And css

```
.TFOOptlstFiltreImg {
background-size: 24px 24px;
height: 24px;
width: 24px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
 .TFOhd.ui-button { 
border: none;
background: none;
padding: 0;
}
```

I add TFOhd just to isolate the effects only on my table. Like that I've automatically the same arrow color than selectmenu